# How test if UseDeveloperExceptionPage middleware is been called in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I'm situation really tricky. I need test if the UseDeveloperExceptionPage middleware is being called when an exception is thrown.
As an attempt to achieve that goal I wrote a bunch of ancillary code.

DiagnosticExceptionAssembly.cs

```cs
namespace TestProjectSample
{
    internal static class DiagnosticExceptionAssembly
    {
        internal const string Assembly = "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.UnhandledException";
    }
}
```

ExceptionMessage.cs

```cs
namespace TestProjectSample
{
    public struct ExceptionMessage
    {
        public string Message { get; set; }
    }
}
```

ExceptionMessageObserver.cs

```cs
using System;

namespace TestProjectSample
{
    public class ExceptionMessageObserver : IExceptionMessage
    {
        public string Message { get; set; }

        public void OnCompleted()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public void OnError(Exception error)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public void OnNext(ExceptionMessage value)
        {
            Message = value.Message;
        }
    }

    public interface IExceptionMessage : IObserver<ExceptionMessage>
    {
        string Message { get; set; }
    }
}
```

ExceptionObserver.cs

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Reflection;

namespace TestProjectSample
{
    public class ExceptionObserver : IObserver<KeyValuePair<string, object>>
    {
        private readonly IObserver<ExceptionMessage> _exceptionMessage;

        public ExceptionObserver(IObserver<ExceptionMessage> exceptionMessage)
        {
            _exceptionMessage = exceptionMessage;
        }

        public void OnCompleted()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public void OnError(Exception error)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public void OnNext(KeyValuePair<string, object> value)
        {
            switch (value.Key)
            {
                case DiagnosticExceptionAssembly.Assembly:
                    var exceptionPayload = value.Value
                        .GetType()
                        .GetTypeInfo()
                        .GetDeclaredProperty("Exception")?
                        .GetValue(value.Value) as string;
                    _exceptionMessage.OnNext(new ExceptionMessage {Message = exceptionPayload});
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

ExceptionSubscriber.cs

```cs
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace TestProjectSample
{
    public class ExceptionSubscriber : IObserver<DiagnosticListener>
    {
        private readonly IObserver<ExceptionMessage> _exceptionMessage;

        public ExceptionSubscriber(IObserver<ExceptionMessage> exceptionMessage)
        {
            _exceptionMessage = exceptionMessage;
        }
        
        public void OnCompleted()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public void OnError(Exception error)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public void OnNext(DiagnosticListener value)
        {
            if (string.Equals(DiagnosticExceptionAssembly.Assembly, value.Name))
            {
                value.Subscribe(new ExceptionObserver(_exceptionMessage));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

DevExceptionPageFacts.cs

```cs
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Net;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.TestHost;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Xunit;

namespace TestProjectSample
{
    public class DevExceptionPageFacts
    {
        private readonly IHostBuilder _hostBuilder;

        private static readonly IExceptionMessage ExceptionMessage = new ExceptionMessageObserver();

        public DevExceptionPageFacts()
        {
            FactSubscriber();
            _hostBuilder = GenerateExceptionHostBuilder();
        }

        private static IHostBuilder GenerateExceptionHostBuilder()
        {
            return new HostBuilder()
                .ConfigureWebHost(builder =>
                {
                    builder.UseTestServer();
                    builder.Configure(applicationBuilder =>
                    {
                        applicationBuilder.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                        applicationBuilder.Run(context => throw new HttpResetTestException(1));
                    });
                });
        }

        private static void FactSubscriber()
        {
            DiagnosticListener.AllListeners.Subscribe(new ExceptionSubscriber(ExceptionMessage));
        }

        [Fact]
        public async Task Throw_DevelopmentPageException()
        {
            var host = await _hostBuilder.StartAsync();
            using var client = host.GetTestClient();
            var response = await client.GetAsync("/");
            Assert.Equal(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, response.StatusCode);
            Assert.NotNull(ExceptionMessage.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

Investigating the source code of UseDeveloperExceptionPage I have noted an injection of DiagnosticSource so that I have decided create a class to listen to when an exception is thrown and caught by middleware. However my test does not pass. Could anyone know how to make this test pass?

Comment: Firstly, why??? Second, the source is online, so are the tests written by the maintainers (https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/f1dd68f1bdd8ed1464b1588c63861da5b314f6cb/src/Middleware/Diagnostics/test/UnitTests/DeveloperExceptionPageMiddlewareTest.cs)

Comment: @JeremyLakeman I have a library that provides a middleware which only trigger the exception page middleware, case some exception is thrown in any controller,  if it were the first in the middleware pipeline.  That is not the expected behavior. The exception page middleware is supposed to be the first in the middleware pipeline, at least in development mode.

Comment: @JeremyLakeman Anyway, I have forgotten that I can see not only the source code but also the test written for any piece of the code related to .Net Core. I will pay attention to the test was written for this case and I will try come to a solution to my case. Thank you!